# Largest Contentful Paint Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, browser

How to Solve the Largest Contentful Paint When the Slick Slider is on Top in desktop lcp is good but in mobile lcp is very bad around 40 to 50.

I am using this slick slider but I am not able to find any solution please tell me how can I solve this.

Comment: Please share the HTML/CSS/JS or URL of your website so that we can look into it. It is impossible to help you with the issue without having any information about your website. It could be anything from large images to slow hosting.

Comment: @RAllen just adding website url https://www.teamsingapore.sg/athleaks?hsCacheBuster=1915 please check and help if u have any solution

Comment: You just need to open the Network tab in Developer Tools in Chrome, reload the page, and sort requests by size. You will immediately see that there are images that are 1,5 Mb and 860 Kb in size. You need to rescale them so that they will be MUCH smaller. Also, there are a lot of PNGs that are used for photos. Use webp or jpeg format for them instead. For example, this https://www.teamsingapore.sg/hubfs/Slide%203.png

Comment: Agree with @RAllen, you can reduce 6x the size (weight) of the image he linked if you convert it to Webp. Now, do the same for all your photo in png and you'll see that you can save few Mb..

Comment: Thank you @Rallen and Amaury Hanser for helping me and telling me the solution.